# Using dask delayed function from within postgresql plpython with "plpy.execute"

Tags: postgresql, dask, plpython, postgres-plpython

The below example demonstrates using dask delayed funtions ([ref](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-sql.html#delayed-functions)) from within postgres plpython while using "plpy.execute" ([ref](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython-database.html)) to query the database.

It returns an error:

`ERROR:  spiexceptions.StatementTooComplex: stack depth limit exceeded`

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong? I'm guessing it has something to do with delayed function's async nature and plpy.execute not liking that.

Versions:

- postgresql 15
- postgres's embedded python version 3.8

Example:

```
DO
LANGUAGE plpython3u
$$

    # https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe-sql.html#delayed-functions
    from dask import delayed
    
    @delayed
    def do_it():
        rv = plpy.execute("select 2 as a") # << max stack depth limit
        return 0

    plpy.info(do_it().compute())

$$;
```

Traceback:

```
ERROR:  spiexceptions.StatementTooComplex: stack depth limit exceeded
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 7168kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python anonymous code block, line 10, in <module>
    plpy.info(do_it().compute())
  PL/Python anonymous code block, line 313, in compute
  PL/Python anonymous code block, line 598, in compute
  PL/Python anonymous code block, line 88, in get
  PL/Python anonymous code block, line 510, in get_async
  PL/Python anonymous code block, line 318, in reraise
  PL/Python anonymous code block, line 223, in execute_task
  PL/Python anonymous code block, line 118, in _execute_task
  PL/Python anonymous code block, line 7, in do_it
    rv = plpy.execute("select 2 as a") # << max stack depth limit
PL/Python anonymous code block
```

Updates:

- added traceback
- made more minimal

Comment: Hi @Shadi, I'm just wondering what you would want to use Dask Delayed into Postgres' embedded Python? Code there is supposed to be minimal right?

Comment: 1) to perform dask operations on postgres data without leaving the server, 2) yes

Comment: What I mean is, will you want to parallelize the code inside Postgres Python? Why don't you just write plain sequential Python code?

Comment: yes, to save the step of moving data out of the postgres server

Comment: Well, I understand that, my point is: do you really need Dask for a Postgres' embedded computation? This doesn't sound appropriate.